# How to mark integer fields as required with Quarkus' Smallrye Openapi plugin in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, openapi, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

I have a simple data class being returned by one of my routes.

Data class:

```kotlin
data class Fruit(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

Route:

```kotlin
@Path("/fruit")
class FruitRoutes {

    @GET
    fun getAllFruit(): Multi<Fruit> {
        return Fruit.findAll()
    }
}
```

The schema generated by the [quarkus-smallrye-openapi extension](https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-openapi) however does not have the `id` as required:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Fruit:
      required:
      - name
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          format: int64
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
```

This extension is a wrapper for [Eclipse Microprofile Open Api](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/).

How can I mark the `id` as required?

I've tried adding the following annotations to the `id` field:

- `@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`
- `@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull`
- `@io.smallrye.common.constraint.NotNull`
- `@org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.Parameter(required = true)`
- `@org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema(required = true)`
- `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty(required = true)`

but with no success

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by changing the data class:

```kotlin
@Schema(requiredProperties = ["id", "name", "createdAt"])
data class Fruit(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

probably a bug with the framework